# Python Telebot issue: TypeError: TeleBot.send_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text'

Tags: python, python-3.x, py-telegram-bot-api

I am new to Python and coding in general.
I'm trying to code up simple Telegram bot on **Python 3.10.6** using **pyTelegramBotAPI 4.7.0.**

This is my code:

```
import telebot;

bot = telebot.TeleBot('*there was my Telegram bot token*');

name = '';
surname = '';
age = 0;

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Hi! I'm another bot for practicing skill :)")

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    if message.text == "hi":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "How can I help you?")
    elif message.text == "/help":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Registration - /reg")
    elif message.text == '/reg':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Nice! Lets sign you up! What is your name?");
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_name);
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Sorry, I don't understand that. Write /help")
def get_name(message):
    global name;
    name = message.text;
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Okay! What is your surname?');
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_surname);
def get_surname(message):
    global surname;
    surname = message.text;
    bot.send_message('What is your age?');
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_age);
def get_age(message):
    global age;
    while age == 0:
        try:
            age = int(message.text)
        except Exception:
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Oops! I need only number.');
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'You are '+str(age)+'yo, your full name is '+name+' '+surname+'?')        

bot.delete_webhook()
bot.infinity_polling()
```

It's good working just right before getting surname step:
[Screenshot_part1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j12dP.png)
[Screenshot_part2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COTBo.png)

So, right after I sent text as surname it's just stopped registration process.
Bot still working, sending any other text will return

> Sorry, I don't understand that. Write /help

In my IDLE Shell I can see error:

```
2022-08-16 18:33:33,773 (__init__.py:878 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot:
"Infinity polling exception: TeleBot.send_message() missing 1 required
positional argument: 'text'" 2022-08-16 18:33:33,895 (__init__.py:880
MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "Exception traceback: Traceback (most
recent call last):   File
"C:\Users\Кирилл\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py",
line 874, in infinity_polling
    self.polling(non_stop=True, timeout=timeout, long_polling_timeout=long_polling_timeout,   File
"C:\Users\Кирилл\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py",
line 946, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(non_stop=non_stop, interval=interval, timeout=timeout, long_polling_timeout=long_polling_timeout,   File
"C:\Users\Кирилл\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py",
line 1021, in __threaded_polling
    raise e   File "C:\Users\Кирилл\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py",
line 977, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()   File "C:\Users\Кирилл\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py",
line 154, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info   File "C:\Users\Кирилл\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py",
line 98, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:/Users/Кирилл/Desktop/bot/bot.py", line 32, in get_surname
    bot.send_message('What is your age?'); TypeError: TeleBot.send_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text'
"
```

Comment: You have `bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'some text')` all over the place; but the line in the error, `bot.send_message('What is your age?');` has no `message.from_user.id` argument. I assume you forgot to pass in a user ID. You are passing in text as the user ID, and are not passing in anything to the text argument at all.

Comment: How to mark your answer as final answer and close question?

Comment: I can post an answer, that was just a comment. just give me a minute. once I post the answer you can upvote it and accept it (after maybe a bit of a delay, I'm not sure, I haven't asked a question on here before)

Comment: Can't upvote due to low reputation, but marked as accepted answer ✅

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(re-posting comment as answer)

You have `bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'some text')` all over the place; but the line in the error, `bot.send_message('What is your age?');` has no `message.from_user.id argument`. I assume you forgot to pass in a user ID. You are passing in text as the user ID, and are not passing in anything to the text argument at all.